# Car starts only sometimes

Tags: starting, lexus, no-crank-no-start, is350

My car starts sometimes then others it doesn’t. I have a 2006 Lexus is350. All electronics work when I push to start, Battery connections are fine, just replaced the alternator, tried my best to check all wiring is good and replaced a blown fuse but yet it’s on and off.

Not sure if it’s the starter/solenoid because it doesn’t make a clicking noise just sort of a hissing noise under the car by the downpipe drivers side when I step on the brake and push start, also where the starter is located

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: hissing like spinning?